# How Do We remove "this page has in-secure content" from facebook that players see before joining?

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps

Our server is secure, we have followed all rules and are now beta testing our game located at http://apps.facebook.com/cityfederation/  The problem is new players (we have testers all over the world) all see this page that says "this page has in-secure content" 
All players see this and it says Facebook recommends that player does not load this game.

We have tested advertising on Facebook and this warning would prevent anyone from joining even though you can clearly see from screenshot that the url is https://apps.cityfederation...

Does anyone know how to correct this as it would be costly to advertise on Facebook at $1 or so per click and then lose 75% of people when they see this.  Plus we'd like to be able to grow in Facebook and this isn't helping.

This will not let me post a screenshot due to being new member here in stackoverflow but anyone can see if you try to play the game. Search for City Federation in Facebook.

Answer (score 1):

The console says:

```
[blocked] The page at https://cityfederation.com/testing/examples/ ran insecure content 
from http://script.opentracker.net/?site=cityfederation.com.
```

This is where your problem comes from.

Comment: Question: When you say "the console says" what program are you running to get that feedback?

Comment: Your browser has a javascript console that shows this kind of information.

If you are using Chrome or Firefox, ctrl+shift+j to show the console.

Comment: Ah, cool, thanks--I've looked through the developer's tools before, but when you said console I thought maybe you were talking about a CLI type program. Cheers.

Comment: FYI, if you can't see the message, it's probably because you didn't enable secure browsing on facebook.